# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'flash'

Tags: python, django

I badly need your help. I am currently trying to pass a string value using flash but I am not sure if I got it correctly.

This is my code:

```
def first_view(request):
    request.flash['message'] = 'Operation succeeded!'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(second_view))

def second_view(request):
    print request.flash['message']                    
    request.flash.keep('message')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(third_view))
```

I'd like to pass the message "Operation Succeeded" to second_view() through HttpResponseRedirect however I got this error message. I am new to python and django so this does not really make a clear sense to me. Your help is so much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the django messages framework for this matter? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default the django HttpRequest object doesn't have an attribute named flash. That's why you are getting this error. You can see available attributes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects

But there's no reason why you can't add one.

```
def first_view(request):
    request.flash = {'message'] : 'Operation succeeded!'}
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(second_view))

def second_view(request):
    try:
        print request.flash['message']                    
        request.flash.keep('message')
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(third_view))
```

But from where your `flash.keep` comes from i have no idea!! As pointed out by [wtower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940098/wtower) it's more usual to rely on the [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) for this sort of thing.